# Android : Creating a vertical space for ImageView and tab

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am working on an Android project in which I am creating UI for editing a Note object in the app. For that, I will be replicating the UI which is designed with JS,HTML,CSS. Unfortunately, android has discrete elements like ListView, TextView and all. As you can see in the screenshot, the top horizontal bar is just a representation and inside it contains a photo.

[image]

Also, there is a tab like option in the activity itself. I don't know how to create both these things. The choice of colour I am planning to create with a List and get the element clicked in the List. I have basic functionality working, and working on UI part now.

I don't know what all is required for creating such fancy UI's. Any help would be nice.

edit_note.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteTagEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteTextEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.97"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noteDate"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noteNumber"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/attachCount"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/attachmentDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:numColumns="2"

        />
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveNoteButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="@string/saveNote" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelEditButton"
                android:layout_width="98dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                />


        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code :

```
public class EditNoteActivity extends Activity {


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_note);
}

    public class getNoteByItsId extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ResponseEntity<RestNote>> {


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ResponseEntity<RestNote> params) {
            restNote = params.getBody();
            restAttachmentList = restNote.getNotesAttachments();

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restSectionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (RestAttachment restAttachment : restAttachmentList) {
                HashMap<String, String> restAttachmentDisplay = new HashMap<>();
                restAttachmentDisplay.put(fileName, restAttachment.getFileName());
                restAttachmentDisplay.put(fileSize, readableFileSize(restAttachment.getFileSize()));
                restSectionArrayList.add(restAttachmentDisplay);
            }

            attachmentsGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.attachmentDisplay);

            noteDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteDate);
            noteDate.setText(restNote.getNoteDate());

            noteNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteNumber);
            String noteNos = "#" + String.valueOf(restNote.getNoteNumber());
            noteNumber.setText(noteNos);

            attachCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attachCount);
            attachCount.setText(String.valueOf(restNote.getAttachCount()));

            editNoteAttachments = new EditNoteAttachments(editNoteActivity, restSectionArrayList);

            attachmentsGridView.setAdapter(editNoteAttachments);
}

    public class EditNoteAttachments extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;


        public EditNoteAttachments(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
            activity = a;
            data = d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attachment_rows, parent, false);

            TextView fileName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.fileName);
            TextView fileSize = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.fileSize);

            HashMap<String, String> conversationList;
            conversationList = data.get(position);

            fileName.setText(conversationList.get(EditNoteActivity.fileName));
            fileSize.setText(conversationList.get(EditNoteActivity.fileSize));
            return vi;
        }

    }
```

Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the top horizontal bar you definitely need a compound custom view like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/title"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImageView"
  android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
  />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    />

</merge>
```

With code like this:

```
public class TopBarView extends RelativeLayout {

  private TextView title;
  private ImageView profileImage;

public TopBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
    R.styleable.TopBarView, 0, 0);
String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.TopBarView_titleText);
a.recycle();

setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_top_bar, this, true);

title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText(titleText);

profileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
profileImage.setBackgroundColor(R.color.yellow);
profileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.myProfileDrawable);
setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
```

For tab options you could use `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` from design support library.

Comment: How can I define this custom view in the activity?

Comment: @We are Borg, here's the related article [link](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html), just add this view into your activity layout file.